# Algoritmos Voraces

Tags: java, algoritmos

Soy estudiante de programación y quisiera saber si alguno me puede dar una idea de como realizar el siguiente problema utilizando algoritmos voraces.

> Encontrar una buena solución para el siguiente problema usando un algoritmo voraz. Explicar el funcionamiento del algoritmo: cuál es el conjunto de candidatos, la función de selección, la función para añadir un elemento a la solución, el criterio de finalización, el criterio de coste, etc.
>
> En una votación existen **n** candidatos y **m** votantes. La probabilidad de que un votante **i** vote al candidato **j** la conocemos a priori, y viene dada por **P[i, j]**. Un votante cualquiera **a** puede ser coaccionado para que vote al candidato que queramos, por ejemplo el **p**, para lo cual tenemos que pagarle **C[a]** ptas. Con esto, nos aseguramos que **P[a, p] = 1**, y **P[a, j] = 0**, para **j ≠ p**.
>
> El objetivo consiste en gastarse la mínima cantidad de dinero, coaccionando a los votantes necesarios, para garantizar que un candidato **p** dado se llevará al menos el 70% de los votos (de acuerdo con las probabilidades esperadas). La solución estará compuesta por la lista de votantes a los cuales hay que coaccionar.
>
> Aplicar el algoritmo diseñado al siguiente ejemplo: **n** = 2 candidatos, **m** = 7 votantes, **p** = 1. Porcentajes y costes de coacción:
>
> ```
>                           Votantes
>         +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+
>         |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  | 7 |
>         +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+
> P[i, 1] | 0.2 | 0.1 | 0.8 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 0 |
> P[i, 2] | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.2 | 0.5 | 0.4 | 0.8 | 1 |
>         +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+
> C[i]       4     3     2     5     3     3    5
> ```

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: Hasta donde conozco, los algoritmos voraces suelen iniciar con un paso de pre procesamiento de los datos como ordenamiento, y luego se procede a realizar el verdadero procesamiento de los datos.

Comment: Ummm, creo que eso es falso.

Answer (score 3):

Los algoritmos voraces pueden ser resueltos con ordenación o sin ella, depende de la estrategia que se decida emplear, yo lo he resuelto realizando ordenación previa del *conjunto candidatos*. Vamos con el código:

Clase que representa la entidad votante, tiene la probabilidad de voto, un costo, un costo aplicado, es decir cuanto dinero nos supone conseguir una probabilidad del 100% para obtener el voto y un identificador del votante.

```
public class Votante {

  private final String idVotante;
  private final float probabilidadVoto;
  private final int costo;
  private final float costoAplicado;


  public Votante(String idVotante, float probabilidadCandidato, int costo) {
    this.idVotante = idVotante;
    this.probabilidadVoto=probabilidadCandidato;
    this.costo = costo;
    this.costoAplicado = (1 - probabilidadVoto) * costo;
  }

  public String getIdCandidato() {
    return idVotante;
  }

  public float getProbabilidadVoto() {
    return probabilidadVoto;
  }

  public int getCosto() {
    return costo;
  }

  public float getCostoAplicado() {
    return this.costoAplicado;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer("Votante: ").append(idVotante)
            .append(" - Probabilidad de voto: ").append(probabilidadVoto)
            .append(" - Costo de corrupcion: ").append(costo)
            .append(" - Costo en base a probabilidad: ").append(costoAplicado);
    return str.toString();
  }

}
```

Por otro lado vamos a implementar un *Comparator* para odenar nuestro *conjunto candidatos* de tal forma que la probabilidad de voto sea de mayor a menor, si se da la misma probabilidad entonces ordena por el coste de menor a mayor:

```
public class ComparadorDeVotantes implements Comparator<Votante> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Votante v1, Votante v2) {
    if(v1.getProbabilidadVoto()==v2.getProbabilidadVoto()) {
        return v1.getCosto() < v2.getCosto() ? -1 : v1.getCosto() == v2.getCosto() ? 0: -1 ;
    }
    return v1.getProbabilidadVoto() > v2.getProbabilidadVoto() ? -1 : 1;
  }

}
```

Defino un interface trivial para representar la funcionalidad del algoritmo, recibe un *conjunto cadidatos* y devuelve un *conjunto solucion*:

```
public interface AlgoritmoVoraz<T> {

  public List<T> procesa(List<T> candidatos);

}
```

Ahora implementamos una clase para resolver este problema

```
public class AlgoritmoCostoCorrupcion implements AlgoritmoVoraz<Votante> {

  private String candidatoElectoral;

  public AlgoritmoCostoCorrupcion(String candidatoElectoral) {
    this.candidatoElectoral=candidatoElectoral;
  }

  @Override
  public List<Votante> procesa(List<Votante> listaDeVotantes) {
    //ordenamos el conjunto candidatos
    Collections.sort(listaDeVotantes, new ComparadorDeVotantes());
    //creamos el conjunto solucion, inicialmente vacio
    List<Votante> solucion = new ArrayList<Votante>();
    //guardamos el numero de elementos del conjunto candidato para poder 
    //calcular porcentaje de procesamiento posteriormente
    int elementosTotales = listaDeVotantes.size();
    //sumatorio para calcular el costo de corrupcion de los votantes
    float costoCorrupcion = 0; 

    //iteramos mientras no tengamos una solucion valida
    while (!esSolucion(solucion.size(), elementosTotales, 70)) {
        //como el conjunto candidato esta ordenado la seleccion es
        //tan simple como obtener siempre el primero
        Votante candidato = seleccionarCandidato(listaDeVotantes);
        //sumamos
        costoCorrupcion = costoCorrupcion + candidato.getCostoAplicado();
        //añadimos al conjunto solucion
        solucion.add(candidato);
        //eliminamos del conjunto candidato
        listaDeVotantes.remove(candidato);
    }
    //conjunto solucion
    return solucion;
  }

  //obtiene el primer elemento del conjunto candidato
  private Votante seleccionarCandidato(List<Votante> listaDeVotantes) {
    return listaDeVotantes.get(0);
  }

  //es solucion cuando se han procesado el 70% o mas de los elementos
  //del conjunto candidato, no es necesario mas al estar ordenados
  private boolean esSolucion(int elementosProcesados, int elementosMaximos, int porcentajeMinimo) {
    return (elementosProcesados * 100) / elementosMaximos > porcentajeMinimo;
  }

//muestra resultado
public void print(List<Votante> solucion) {
    float costoCorrupcion=0;
    System.out.println("Datos del conjunto solucion:");
    for (Votante elementoDeSolucion : solucion) {
        System.out.println("\t"+elementoDeSolucion.toString());
        costoCorrupcion = costoCorrupcion + elementoDeSolucion.getCostoAplicado();
    }
    System.out.println("El coste de corrupcion minimo es de : " + costoCorrupcion + " para el candidato: " 
            + candidatoElectoral + "con al menos el 70% de los votantes");

  }

}
```

Test para su comprobación:

```
public class AlgoritmoCostoCorrupcionTest {

  @Test
  public void testProcesa() {
    List<Votante> listaDeVotantes=new ArrayList<Votante>();
    listaDeVotantes.add(new Votante("Votante1",0.2f,4));
    listaDeVotantes.add(new Votante("Votante2",0.1f,3));
    listaDeVotantes.add(new Votante("Votante3",0.8f,2));
    listaDeVotantes.add(new Votante("Votante4",0.5f,5));
    listaDeVotantes.add(new Votante("Votante5",0.6f,3));
    listaDeVotantes.add(new Votante("Votante6",0.2f,3));
    listaDeVotantes.add(new Votante("Votante7",0f,5));

    AlgoritmoCostoCorrupcion ccc=new AlgoritmoCostoCorrupcion("Candidato A");
    List<Votante>solucion=ccc.procesa(listaDeVotantes);
    ccc.print(solucion);

    assertThat(solucion.size(),is(equalTo(5)));
  }

}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, sin ordenación previa la implementación para mi es mas complicada, lo mismo a ti no te lo parece.

Answer (score 0):

Los algoritmos voraces deciden la opción más beneficiosa en cada estado del problema. 
En este caso creo que la idea es elegir primero el votante con el menor costo que beneficie más a la votación del candidato 1. Luego el que le sigue en costo/beneficio y así sucesivamente hasta alcanzar el objetivo de asegurar el 70%.
Espero que te ayude.